# Configure Rollup to add file extensions into import/require statements

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs, rollupjs

I have a hybrid cjs/esm Node package written in Typescript.

It consists of, let's say, two files - `core.ts` and `extra.ts` and I want to keep them separate. `extra.ts` imports `core.ts` (literally `import { ... } from './core';`) and they are separate entry points of the package. Clients import either only `core.ts` or both.

Rollup makes it easy to have build steps for multiple entry points, for multiple output formats, and all seemed fine.

But now I ran into an issue:

Let's say I have `example.mjs` or `example.cjs` where I import or require `my-package` and `my-package/extra` entry points.

That doesn't work. Error messages are slightly different but meaning is the same - `./core` module can not be found when reading `extra.mjs/cjs`.

- `extra.cjs` built by Rollup contains the line `var core = require('./core');`
- `extra.mjs` built by Rollup contains the line `import { ... } from './core';`

By default, Node 12 does not guess file extensions (I'm not questioning this).

I have to call it as `node --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node ./example.mjs` to make it work. This is unsatisfactory solution. I need `example.mjs` to be runnable without additional flags.

It appears to me that file extensions can and should be added to import/require statements in compiled cjs/mjs files to make it work according to the spec.

Although, since I have different build steps in Rollup config for both files and `external: ['./core']` in the options for `extra.ts`, for Rollup they are totally unrelated. And Rollup will just bundle them into a single file otherwise, which is not what I need either.

So the question:

- Is there a plugin or a configuration option to make Rollup produce files with correct local imports (file extensions added to local imports according to the format)?
- What would be the best way to add an extra step to the building process to patch imports if there is no existing solution?
- Maybe there a different bundler that might work for the same task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a satisfactory solution.

`output.preserveModules` option keeps all files separate while building them in one pass (can be limiting in some aspects though).

`output.entryFileNames` option allows to specify file extensions. (It won't work with modules considered external, can't use it without preserveModules.)

I can build only `extra.ts` as it imports every other file. But I have to be mindful of tree shaking when building like this - need to retain all exports of `core.ts`.

```js
export default [
  {
    external: [],
    input: 'src/extra.ts',
    treeshake: false,
    plugins: [
      typescript(),
      cleanup({ extensions: ['ts'] })
    ],
    output: [
      {
        dir: 'lib',
        format: 'es',
        preserveModules: true,
        entryFileNames: '[name].mjs',
      },
      {
        dir: 'lib',
        format: 'cjs',
        preserveModules: true,
        entryFileNames: '[name].cjs',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

One step back is that I get another output file for another ts file imported by `core.ts` and `extra.ts`. I think I can live with that.

Ideal solution would require to monkey-patch output files with sed-like tool after the build in my initial configuration.